# How to Pass Array Model as a value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model

I have a model class name called APIEntity. and that has DataObject[].The DataObject has 10 members now i want to pass the members as value. How do i do that ?

This is my model:

```
public class APIEntity
{
    public List<int> unitCodes { get; set; }
    public DateTime start { get; set; }

    public DateTime end { get; set; }
    public DataObject[] fields { get; set; }
}

public class DataObject
{
    public string unitCode { get; set; }
    public string timedate { get; set; }
    public string latitude { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
    public string ignition { get; set; }
    public string velocity { get; set; }
    public string positionerror { get; set; }
    public string digitherm5 { get; set; }
    public string direction { get; set; }
    public string distance { get; set; }
}
```

I am just trying to pass the values:

```
var dat = new APIEntity()
{
    unitCodes = new List<int>() { 19215 },
    start = DateTime.ParseExact("2018-03-12 10:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null),
    end = DateTime.ParseExact("2018-03-12 11:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null),
    fields = ?????? // I want to pass the members here...unitcode,timedate,bla bla....
};
```

Comment: What should be the data type of `fields` property?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var dat = new APIEntity()
{
    unitCodes = new List<int>() { 19215 },
    start = DateTime.ParseExact("2018-03-12 10:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null),
    end = DateTime.ParseExact("2018-03-12 11:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null),
    fields = new DataObject[] 
    {
        new DataObject { unitCode = "unitCode", timedate  = "timedate " }, 
        new DataObject { unitCode = "unitCode", timedate  = "timedate " }
    }
};
```